# Cases Automatically Closing when Opportunity Closed Won

Tags: case, opportunity

Cases related to an Opportunity are all automatically being closed when the Opportunity it being set to Closed Won.

Is this standard operation with Salesforce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no standard way to relate a case to an opportunity, so this is all obviously custom configuration. You'll need to check for Processes and triggers to see what might be going on. You can also check your debug logs to determine what's going on.